# Odd problem with USB tethering: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) or Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: tethering, connection-issues, usb-tethering

I am accessing internet with my Laptop through 3G USB Tethering from my Nexus S with Android 4.0.4.

About half of the time, I lose connection and I am unable to access any website on my Laptop or use any application that connects to the internet (eg. ping), except for Gmail and Skype (which still work very well). And it goes back and forth frequently between the normal situation and the odd one.

If I try to access any other website on my laptop (like google.com), I get depending on the website:

"No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."

OR

"This webpage is not available
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection"

Do you have an explanation for this bizarre behavior? Do you think an app is interfering with my connection?

Comment: At the time of having problem, does browsing problematic sites work in your phone?

Comment: When I have this problem, I also have at the same time browsing problem on my phone (Connection problem: a network error has occured). And vice-versa when in normal mode

Comment: Then maybe the problem lies at the ISP.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes rooting may cause such problems.
The phone says "unrooted" or otherwise, bans some programs, i.e. browser, etc., from functioning properly.
I would suggest to apply a factory reset - of course after having all the back up you may possibly need - rather than flashing a clean firmware.